# Why I can't send ether through this code?

Tags: solidity, transactions, ether

I have written the following code for testing.

I can successfully send dummy ERC20 tokens by calling the createSwap function on contract A by whitelisting the contract addresses on goerli

For test purposes I have set the whitelisted address for Ether to the null address.

When I'm trying to send Ether, I keep getting on Remix

```
"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":7219392785628617}"
```

I tried through javascript and set different gasPrice and gasLimit but still getting error `"[ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]"`

```
contract A {
    B public b;

    function link(address _b) public {
        b = B(_b);
    }

    mapping(address => bool) public isWhitelisted;

    function setWhitelist(address _asset) public {
        isWhitelisted[_asset] = true;
    }

    function createSwap(address asset, uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(isWhitelisted[asset]);
        if(asset == address(0)) {
            b.myTransfer{value: amount}(asset, msg.sender, amount); 
        } else {
            b.myTransfer(asset, msg.sender, amount);
        }
    }
}

contract B {
    function myTransfer(address asset, address from, uint256 amount) public payable {
        if(amount == 0 || asset == address(0)) return;
        IERC20(asset).transferFrom(from, address(this), amount);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use tools like Hardhat or Truffle to debug and identify which line in the contract code is causing the revert to happen.

Comment: Please include the code that calls the function? The issue is most likely there

Comment: When using Remix to hit the contract, what value are you inputting in the `amount` field of your `createSwap` function?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`Please make sure msg.value >= amount`.

Comment: I'm using goerli

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by using :
using Address for address payable;
on contract B